# Delphi 5 BPLs Not Linking For One Program Only

Tags: delphi, linker

I'm still using Delphi 5.

I have a program which is a rewrite of an earlier program and in fact uses the root unit from the earlier program.  When I compile it, Delphi doesn't link the BPLs into the EXE for some reason.  New programs and old programs compile fine, so the problem is obviously with this one program.   I've compared the project options for Linking and Compiling with other programs which are linking just fine.   The compiler options in the main unit are the standard ones.

While the program is on my development box, it runs as expected, obviously reading the BPLs in the development area.   But of course it won't run on another machine unless I copy the BPLs over, which is obviously not very clever.

I've read everything I can find on the subject, but although I've found references to linking not working, I haven't found anything which helps to work out why the linking isn't working in just this one case.

Can anyone point me at some documentation about this or point out something I've obviously missed looking at?   I know it's something I've done, but despite spending hours on it I can't work out why!

Since there are no errors generated, I can't show you where it went wrong.   Any suggestions about where I might find the problem would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you go to the Packages tab of your Project Options, is the `Build with runtime packages` checked?  If it is, you need to deploy the other packages to other machines.  If it isn't, the code from the DCUs in the packages will be statically linked into your .EXE and you won't need to deploy the .BPLs.

Comment: Are you compiling with the runtime packages option selected?  If so, the BPLs are not bundled into the application by the linker - the program expects to find them on the host computer in the same way it would look for a DLL.  Disable runtime packages if you want a monolithic application.

Comment: Btw, AFAIK if `Build with runtime packages` isn't checked, the compiler gets the other units' code to link from the .DCU files, rather than from the .BPL files, contrary to the impression my previous comment might have given.

Comment: MartynA, J, the Build with Runtime Packages option is checked for ALL of my programs - it is the default option.    They certainly don't complain about there being no packages when they run - except in this case.   I just tried compiling the program with the box unchecked and it complained about missing .dcu files.   Which are in the Delphi path!

Comment: Well, if you do a Build, it should either find the DCUs, compile the corresponding .PAS files if it can't find them or complain that it can't find the sources.  This q needs a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), istm.  It is lacking the details needed to diagnose the problem.

Comment: MartynA, thanks for your response.   It at least proved that I'd been looking the correct area and not missing some arcane coding problem.    I'll play with the Build with Runtime Packages option and see where it gets me.

Comment: If you put that up as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: If *Build with Runtime Packages* is checked, then you have to distribute the runtime packages (BPL files) with your application. If you want the code linked into the application itself, **uncheck** "Build with Runtime Packages*.  Read the documentation about that option by clicking the *Help* button with that option page open. This has been how it worked since runtime packages were first introduced, and continues to work that way in the current 10.4 Sydney of Delphi.

Comment: I've posted my comments into an answer.

Comment: Better late than never - thanks Martyn, you were right, and I was "misreading" the meaning of that checkbox.  Sorted now!    Apologies for the lateness - I'm not a professional programmer and I don't do a lot of coding.   It's easy to forget the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to the Packages tab of your Project Options, is the Build with runtime packages checked?

If it is, you need to deploy the other packages to other machines if they aren't already on those machines at locations where they can be found by the OS.

If it isn't, Delphi will compile and link your project as an .Exe file and the code from the DCUs in the packages will be statically linked into your .Exe so you won't need to deploy the .BPLs (and they would be ignored even if you did).

AFAIK, when Delphi compiles a project to an .Exe (that is, if Build with runtime packages isn't checked), the compiler gets the other units' code to link from the .DCU files, rather than from the .BPL files.  If it can't find the .DCU files, or you have told the compiler to do a "Build" it will attempt to generate the .DCUs them from the corresponding .PAS files if it can find them either in the project directory or via the `Seach Path` under Directories/Conditionals.